# Storing a remote hosted image on S3 directly using java sdk

Tags: amazon-s3

I know I can download the image on server and then upload again to S3 or any other cloud hosting service, but is there any way to store the image asset directly on s3 by supplying URL of asset instead of a file, because I don't want to add unwanted download and upload on my server.

Note: I am assured that the URI will be 99.9% up and image file will also be there. And I am OK to use services other than S3 if they have such a feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is no API call for Amazon S3 that will retrieve content from another location.

You must supply the content as part of the API call.